# react-redux TypeError: notes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why am I getting `TypeError: notes.map is not a function` in the following part of my Notes component? `{notes.map((note) => (`

components/Notes.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { notes: state.notes }
}

const NotesList = ({ notes }) => (
  <ul className="notes_list">
    {notes.map((note) => (
      <li className="note_body" key={note.id}>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: note.body }}></div>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

const Notes = connect(mapStateToProps)(NotesList);
export default Notes;
```

reducers/notes.js

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
  notes: [{id: 1, body: "hey"}]
}

function notes(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default notes
```

root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import notes from './notes'
import noteForm from './noteForm'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  notes,
  noteForm
})

export default rootReducer
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Notes from './components/Notes'
import NoteForm from './components/NoteForm'    

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <NoteForm />
    <Notes />
  </div>
)

export default App
```

**---upd**

store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import rootReducer from '../reducers'
import {ping} from './enhancers/ping'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk, ping))

  return store
}
```

index.js

```
...
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: When you get 'map isn't a function' that's mean you're not calling your data correctly, I see in notes reducer page you're not calling the states correctly change it to `function notes(state = initialState.notes, action)`

Comment: @Liam, thanks, it worked. Is it normal to calling it this way? I haven't seen any examples similar to this one

Comment: Actually, it's depending on you I've added an answer with the regular way these two ways works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you providing the `connect` function with a store? If so, everything looks fine to me -- it'd be useful to see your store initialization code.

Create a store with `createStore` from `redux` and wrap your `App` with a `Provider` from `react-redux`:

app.js

```
...

import notesReducer from './reducers/notes'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const store = createStore(notesReducer) // use combineReducers when you add a 2nd reducer

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div className="App">
      <NoteForm />
      <Notes />
    </div>
  </Provider>
)
```

If you already have a Provider somewhere else, check if everything's okay there.

Here's my fully working example - I copied your Notes.js file and wrote up the following App.js - no errors whatsoever (I bundled store creation and reducers all in one file for simplicity):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import Notes from './Notes'

const initialState = {
  notes: [{
    id: 1,
    body: 'testing'
  }]
}

function notes(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(notes)

export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Notes />
  </Provider>
)
```

**Update for `combineReducers`**

When using `combineReducers`, your reducers' `initialState` will already be namespaced in the store under the key which was used in the `combineReducers` call. Change your notes reducer's `initialState` to an array:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'

// no need for { notes: [] } here, combineReducers({ notes }) will take care of that
const initialState = [{ id: 1, body: 'hey' }]

function notes(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default notes
```

Comment: added store part to my question

Comment: Okay, you're already splitting reducers with combineReducers.

In that case, you shouldn't have the additional "notes" object in your notes' reducer initialState - with combineReducers it will already be under "notes" in the store. Just change your notes' reducer initialState to an array :)

To elaborate, your store currently looks like { notes: { notes: [] } }. The first "notes" comes from the combineReducers call, the second one from your initialState.

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it's clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

When you get `map isn't a function` that means you're not calling the data correctly.

I see in notes reducer page you're not calling the states correctly

```
function notes(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Change it to:

```
function notes(state = initialState.notes, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

The regular way to do this is to not putting your states in an array

```
const initialState = {
  id: 1, 
  body: "hey"
}

function notes(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   ...
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This will works fine

Answer (score 0):

since my root reducer has the following structure

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  notes
})
```

I can reach notes by `state.notes.notes`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { notes: state.notes.notes }
}
```

having the following initial state structure for notes

```
const initialState = {
  notes: []
}
```